# Is the content from style sheet part of DOM?

Tags: html, css, dom

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Content) says: *Content specified in a stylesheet does not become part of the DOM.*

Below is the code,

```
html:
A text where I need to <span class="ref">something</span>

css:
.ref::before {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: navy;
  content: "refer: ";
}
```

for which the DOM inspector shows the content under DOM:

### [image]

How do I understand the above statement from MDN article?

Comment: It is a fake element, not part of the DOM. `:after` and `:before` are fake. You can call them fake/virtual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the content from style sheet part of DOM?

No

> for which the DOM inspector shows the content under DOM

Don't read too much into that. It's a useful tool for debugging. It does not make the content part of the DOM. You cannot address it with the DOM API.

Comment: Don't read? Please tell me, whether DOM inspector is misguiding by showing the `pseudo-element` in DOM tree.

Comment: @overexchange — It's an [idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/read+into). It isn't misguided, being able to see psuedo-elements with debugging tools is a useful feature. You're just putting too much meaning into the name "DOM inspector".

Answer (score 4):

`::before` is a *pseudo* element - it is represented in the console, yes, but anything else interacting with the DOM does not detect it. You can't target a `:before` with javascript, for example. Don't confuse your inspector with the actual DOM.

CSS is *not* a document object, it is *how such object should be displayed*.

Comment: Are you saying that inspector can show pseudo-elements that are not part   of DOM?

Comment: @overexchange Yes thats exactly what it is. Different browsers behave differently on that front, Chrome displays them as `:before` and `:after` _nodes_, nested inside their host element, safari only shows them as styles in the style inspector... They are just there so you can easily see how your page is working and find and style things.

Comment: Is inspector not suppose to show the content that is part of DOM? What else does it display?

Comment: The inspector is a development tool and therefor shows the things that are most relevant when developing a page. It is very useful to know that CSS insert a pseudo element before a link, in case you would be wondering 'what is displaying that arrow in front of my link?'. I cant really come up with other things that it displays, but the inspector allows you to inspect elements and the pseudo elements are part of the styling of these elements, so it shows all of it. Its just a tool, and not an actual DOM tree.